# JavaScript Date calculation and conversion issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do some date calculations in javascript but having trouble:

```
var days = 5;
var init_date = '22-DEC-21';
var result;

today = new Date();
result = today - days;
```

`result` I expect to have a date value but it is a numeric value. How can I convert it to date?

Also the variable `init_date` will need to be converted to date and compared with `result`. How can this be done in JavaScript?

Comment: My recommendation would be to use a date library instead of the js Date API directly, unless you plan to study its docs in and out. You can easily achieve what you want with various libs, one [example](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) has a nice API, for your case: `moment().subtract(days, 'days')` and `moment(init_date, "DD-MMM-YY").subtract(days, 'days')`.

Comment: Please spend some time to write your question properly. Variable `init_date` is not used anywhere in your code, "converted to date" seems meaningless with regards to this variable (since it already IS a date), and "to be compared" is also unclear, as there are many different types of comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: Mister Jojo, that is exactly what I tried but the result was numeric not date

Answer (score 2):

To get date minus, say 5 days you can use methods of JS Date() API like this:

```
let date = new Date();
date.setDate((date.getDate() - 5));
```

Note: it will return the date in milliseconds, like this:

```
//1642972791097
```

To convert it to standard date, use this:

```
new Date(1642972791097);
//Sun Jan 23 2022 23:19:51 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)
```

To convert it to local date format, use this:

```
new Date(1642972791097).toLocaleDateString()
//'1/23/2022'
```

To properly parse the string representation like '22-DEC-21' you will need to keep helper object monthsNames. See code example:

```
let monthsNames = {
    'JAN': 0,
    'FEB': 1,
    'MAR': 2,
    'APR': 3,
    'MAY': 4,
    'JUN': 5,
    'JUN': 6,
    'AUG': 7,
    'SEP': 8,
    'OCT': 9,
    'NOV': 10,
    'DEC': 11
}

let initDate = new Date();
let initDateString = '22-DEC-21';
let initDateArray = initDateString.split('-');
initDate.setDate(initDateArray[0]);
initDate.setMonth(monthsNames[initDateArray[1]]);
initDate.setFullYear(Number('20' + initDateArray[2]));

console.log(initDate);
//Wed Dec 22 2021 23:15:47 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)
```

Regarding comparing the dates: the easiest way to converts the dates to milliseconds.
Say, you have 2 variables keeping the dates in standard format: date1 and date2. So:

```
let date1Milli = date1.getTime(); // date in milliseconds
let date2Milli = date2.getTime();
console.log(date1Milli > date2Milli);
// true or false
```

Comment: I did $dt = date.setDate((date.getDate() - $day)) and the result came out numeric, not date

Comment: You are right. Format to standard Date with the command:
new Date(1642972791097)

Comment: Thank you! That did give me the value in a valid date format. Now how can I convert my string date variable init_date to a valid date format and compare to the $dt to see which is greater?

Comment: I updated the answer with a way of converting the string to Date

Comment: Also, updated the answer with a way to compare the dates.

Comment: One quick thing on working with javascript dates to keep an eye on when troubleshooting/converting - day/year are 1 based (so february 14, 2016 will have day and year of 14 and 2016) but month is zero based (so february 14, 2016 will have a month of 1).  Always trips me up!!

Comment: Agree, need be careful with it ))

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to begin with:

```
const daysToSeconds = x => x * 24 * 60 * 60;
const dateToSeconds = x => new Date(x).valueOf() / 1000;
const secondsToDate = x => new Date(x * 1000).toLocaleString().split(",").join("");

const today  = dateToSeconds(new Date());
const days   = daysToSeconds(5);
const result = secondsToDate(today - days);
```

Other than that, it is not really clear what you want to do with `var init_date = '22-DEC-21'`.